# store the current command run in a separate file

Tags: command-line, log

I want to keep a log of all commands I run in a separate log file (other than history) along with other description. To achieve this I need to know how can I fetch current run command and store it in a file.

Scenario:
Currently, Whenever I run sudo command it asks for reason, which I provide. And the reason is stored in log file in my directory. But now I want to store the command run along with the reason and I am not able to find the way to do this.

```
$ sudo touch file
Reason for sudo: creating new file test
[sudo] password for root:
```

Like in above, I want to store the command `sudo touch file` along with reason provided in a file every time I run a command.

Comment: You replaced "sudo:" with a script to obtain this request to provide a reason? As such, the script could then also read the command line arguments, which contain the command run, and also store that also in the log file.

Comment: Thanks vanadium. I used same approach and successfully achieved this. I will be putting that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions. I achieved this using an alias in my `.bashrc` and a shell script.

```
alias sudo='bash $HOME/.sudolog'
```

#### Script `$HOME/.sudolog`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Script to log the sudo commands used with reason.

##                                                                       ##
#LAST UPDATED ON 24 FEB 2019 16:30 IST#
##                                                                       ##

logfile="$HOME/sudo.log"
cmd="sudo $*"

date_time=`date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'` > /dev/null 2>&1
username=`whoami` > /dev/null 2>&1
read -p "Reason for sudo: " reason
eval $cmd
rtrn="$?"
echo "<date time> $date_time </date time>  <user> $username </user>  <command> sudo $* </command>  <reason> $reason </reason>  <return> $rtrn </return>"  >> "$logfile"
```

Comment: Are you sure using `cmd="sudo $*"` and `eval $cmd` rather than `cmd="sudo $@"` and `eval "$cmd"` is a good idea? Try with `sudo touch "a file"`, this should create just *one* file.

Comment: A `bash` shortcut for `> /dev/null 2>&1` is `&>/dev/null`, though I’m not sure what you’re redirecting in these lines…

Comment: $* worked for me well. So haven't checked with $@. Do let me know if it will create any issue in future

Comment: /dev/null 2>&1 is to redirect any error or output to null so that it won't create clutter on terminal

Comment: “If you want to re-use your positional parameters to call another program (for example in a wrapper-script), then this is the choice for you, use double quoted `"$@"`.” ([source](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiny function to override a command of the same name, add your extensions, and then run the actual command e.g. for `sudo` (assuming `bash`):

```bsh
sudo () {
    read -p 'Reason for sudo: ' reason
    printf 'sudo %s : %s\n' "$*" "$reason" >>~/reason_file.txt
    command sudo "$@"
}
```

Put that in any shell session initialization file e.g. `~/.bashrc`. And obviously you can modify the function body to meet your need.

Now when you'll be running`sudo some_command`, the above function will be run and will do the defined operations before eventually running `sudo some_command` with the actual `sudo` external binary.

---

As a side note, all shells store the interactive session history in a separate file e.g. for `bash` it”s `~/.bash_history`, for `zsh` it’s `~/.histfile`. And the `history` builtin command will get you the saved (and buffered) history.